# How do I prevent Intent.createChooser from using the Intent automatically if there is only one intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to create an Intent Chooser for editing a "Profile Picture", with the following options:
1. Camera
2. Gallery
3. Delete Image

Based on the permissions supplied by the user, I am appending cameraIntent & galleryIntent to a list of intents that I add to to the chooser.
However, if the user denies both camera & gallery permissions, the chooser automatically falls back to option 3, Delete Image, which is not what I want.

```
    public Intent getImageChooserIntent(){
            Intent galleryIntent = getGalleryIntent();
            Intent cameraIntent = getCameraIntent();
            Intent imageSourceChooser = Intent.createChooser(new Intent(), "Select Source");
            List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (galleryIntent != null) {
                intentList.add(galleryIntent);
            }
            if (cameraIntent != null) {
                intentList.add(cameraIntent);
            }

            intentList.add(new Intent(context, DeleteImageActivity.class));
            imageSourceChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Intent[0]));
            return imageSourceChooser;

        }
```

I expect the prompt to show a chooser with just one option - "Delete Image", if the user denies permission for both camera & gallery.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way it works though. In your case, if you know the user hasn't granted permission for camera or gallery, you can just show your own dialog asking the user if they want to delete the image.

Comment: I get what you're saying. However, I do ask for permission as well. But if the user were to deny the permission even on run time, the camera or gallery options shouldn't show as the user hasn't allowed for it. Another way to ask this question is, how do I prevent the chooser from just picking the one that's available, instead of showing the options (in this case, just one option)

Comment: You can't :-( That's the way choosers work. If there is only one option it does not ask the user, as that would be stupid. There is only one choice, so the chooser makes it for you. The only way is to not use the chooser if you know there is only one option

Comment: But that'd mean I'd have no uniformity in the way prompts were made to a user. What other way would you recommend to go about it? Is there anything that comes close to duplicating the chooser? (Except for designing it manually to match the chooser exactly)

Comment: Or, how can I request for permissions, after the user clicks on option number 1 or 2

Comment: If you want to launch the camera app with an `Intent`, you don't need to have any special permission. The same for the Gallery. Maybe you are confused about how permissions work.

Comment: I do need permission to access the read and write permissions on gallery so that I can save a picture from gallery, I'm assuming. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes, you do need read/write permissions to read/write files. However, you don't need permission to launch the Gallery app. So you can still include that in your chooser and then deal with the permissions consequences afterwards.